# Sum weekly records for selected month, year for User Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a search engine that selects a User (model), the month (created_at column), year (created_at column) and their Posts (model). Each post has three integer columns. I need to know how to get the total (sum) for each week of the month for these three columns, for the specified user. I will iterate over each week and show the totals underneath the week. How can you do this in rails? I know the cweek attribute gives you the real number for the current week. But, how would I track that information if I use params[:month], params[:year]?

**Week container**

```
<% @user.posts.week.with_index(1) do |week, index| %>
 <p>Week <%= index %></p>
<%= week.total %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. *"Each post has three integer columns"* -- OK, and what are the columns? What do they represent? *"[...] how to get the total (sum) for each week of the month of these three columns"* -- What is a "week of the month"? And how can you convert an integer into a week? What does that even mean?

Comment: Alright, I'll explain it in simpler terms. Each User in my system, can create charts for a month. They'll select a date (including month,year, day) and then they'll fill out 3 integer columns. The search engine itself is an administrative tool. I will review their charts by month/year, and then look at the total sum for each individual column in one area by the week. Two columns on one screen, the weekly totals column, the chart for the month.

Comment: There are up to 5 weeks in each month. I want to iterate over the 5 weeks and get the totals for each 3 integer columns. Week 1 (300, 10, 12), Week 2 (100, 20, 13), Week 3 (120, 23, 14)...up until week 5. This is all records per month on a weekly interval.

Comment: So to clarify: Each post has a date (`created_at`, or whatever), and three unspecified other integer columns (let's say, `col1`, `col2` and `col3`). You want to select all posts in a calendar month, grouped by calendar week, and display `sum(col1)`, `sum(col2)` and `sum(col3)` for each group?

Comment: It might help if you actually said what these columns are all called, otherwise we'll be forced to *guess* your database structure and might just get it wrong.

Comment: medivac_col_1:integer medivac_col_2:integer medivac_col_3:integer

Comment: Yes, I simply want to show each week by count and sum the records for each week. So, that I'll know the total by week for all of the user's posts in the month/year given.

Comment: Its a medical app for doctors, to keep track of statistics on their patients.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217910/discussion-between-dw4050-and-tom-lord).